# Can I use LESS for CSS styling while using Bootstrap 4 as framework?

Tags: bootstrap-4, sass, less, magento2

I am working on a project to convert designs into responsive HTML and CSS and I am using Bootstrap 4 as a framework and I am including the CSS files of the Bootstrap not the SASS files. then, these coded pages will be integrated on Magento 2. What I know is that Magento 2 requires LESS, not Compiled CSS. My question here, Can I use LESS while I am using Bootstrap 4 as a framework?

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can
Just be careful NOT to use  classes that bootstrap 4  is currently used
like

```
btn btn-danger
```